# strange behaviour of cout << Boost::posix_time

Tags: c++, boost, posix

I want to calculate time of a loop that it takes to finish.

I do something like:

```
ptime before = second_clock::local_time(); //get current time
cout << "Started: "<< before << " ... processing ...";
while(foo) {
....
}
ptime after = second_clock::local_time(); // get Current time
cout << "Processing took" << after - before;
```

This will output: Started: "some time"

then I wait for the loop to finish before I get to see " ... processing ..."

Why is that? It should first cout the whole text and then go into the loop.

If I change the first cout to:

cout << "Started: "<< before;

It doesn't even show me the time before the loop finishes.

That's the most weird thing I've ever seen...seems there's something going wrong with my understanding of boost time.

I'm using boost::threads too in my code but workers are spwaned within the loop so I don't see how this could have to do with this problem.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

`ostream`s including `cout` use buffers, which means the implementation can wait to see if you will send more data before actually acting on it.

To get `cout` to print sooner, use

```
std::cout << std::flush;
```

or use `std::endl`, which is equivalent to `"\n"` followed by `std::flush`.